# Segmentation fault when printing out arrays

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is part of the program I am working on, it is copying the file opened and then put it into an array (`file1`). However, I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to print out the content of the `file1`.

I had tried to set the MAX_MAC_ADD to 50 and BIG_NUM to 30000 such that it is big enough to sustain the file from `fgets()`.

The file which I am opening has 4 parts, each separate by a 'tab'

> e.g. 1one     1two       1three      1four
>        2one     2two       2three      2four

```c
char    file1[MAX_MAC_ADD][BIG_NUM];
int         num_MAC = 0;

char    *Programe_Name;

int saperate_fields1(char line[])
{
int i = 0;
int f = 0;

while(line[i] != '\0' && line[i] != '\n')
{
    int c = 0;

    while(line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != '\0' && line[i] != '\n')
    {
        file1[f][c] = line[i];
        ++c;
        ++i;
    }
    file1[f][c] = '\0';

    ++f;
    if(f == (MAX_MAC_ADD-1))
    {
        break;
    }
    ++i;
}
return f,i;
}

void read_file1(char filename[])
{
//OPEN FOR READING
FILE    *fp = fopen(filename,"r");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("%s: cannot open '%s'\n", Programe_Name, filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
char    line[BUFSIZ];
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
{
    saperate_fields1(line);     //SAPERATE INTO FIELDS
    num_MAC = num_MAC + 1;
    printf("%d times\n", num_MAC);
}
fclose(fp);
printf("line is:\n%s\n", line); //TO CHECK WHERE DO THE PROGRAM STOP READING
printf("file1 is:\n%s\n", file1);
}
```

Comment: You may want to use gdb to see where it craps out...then work backward from there. If you still cannot get the problem, please report back. I am sure you will get close to the answer!

Comment: `file1` is not a string, so that print is suspect in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a pointer to an array of `char`s to the format specifier `%s` which expects a pointer to a `char`. If you want to print your array of arrays of `char` you need to print the elements individually, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i != end; ++i) {
    printf("file1[%d]='%s'\n", i, file1[i]);
}
```